# List & Label - Transponate table

Tags: listlabel

With List & Label v25 software I have to generate a compare layout with a table where the datarows are in 4 columb side-by-side and the headers into the 1st row. If we had more than 4 datarow, it comes to a new site...
Any idea how to transponate the table?

Comment: Not sure I'm getting your question, @Szuni. Could you edit and add a screenshot or mockup of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBartlau time solved the problem. The problem was to display the record in a columb. and to display 4-5 record on a page, side by side. In other words a transponated view... But you can forget it.